# How do I write to a text file given a filename through the command line?

Tags: java, file-io, printwriter

I am trying to write to a file with the original path given through the commandline run configurations.  However, I am having a hard time trying to put the pieces together.I am trying to pass the file name through the Report class constructor and then use that to write to the file using a print method.  What am I doing wrong? Sorry, I am very bad at java...

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String roadFilename = args[0];
        String cellNetworkFilename = args[1];
        String imageFilename = args[2];
        String reportFilename = args[3];

    Report report = new Report( 
                new java.io.File(reportFilename)
                );
        report.add(message);
        report.write();
        cellNetwork.hasCoverage(roadNetwork);
    }


public class Report {
    String mess;
    java.util.ArrayList<String> something = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
    File file;
    private PrintWriter print;
    public Report(File file) {


        this.file=file;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void add(String message) {

        something.add(message);

    public void write() {


        try {
            print = new PrintWriter( 
                    new BufferedWriter(
                            new FileWriter(file)));
            print.println(something);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //          e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

Comment: 1) Why aren't you closing the file?, 2) why is `e.printStackTrace();` commented out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the contents of the ArrayList, which holds the messages you added. Not the ArrayList itself. Trying to print it like this:

```
print.println(something);
```

will cause the pointer String to be printed to the file rather than the contents.

You probably need to loop through the array list and print its contents line by line.

```
for(String string: something) {
    print.println(string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to close the PrintWriter at the end.

```
try {
    print = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if(print != null) {
    print.println(something);
    print.close();
}
```